# Как сделать что бы при нажатии на On вибрировала кнопка TEST а при нажатии на Off не вибрировала

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать что бы при нажатии на On вибрировала кнопка TEST а при нажатии на Off не вибрировала

```
  <button id="vibro_on">ON</button>
  <button id="vibro_off">OFF</button>

  <button onclick="vibro()">TEST</button>

  <script>
  function vibro() {

    if( document.getElementById("vibro_on") ) {
    navigator.vibrate([50])
    } else ( document.getElementById("vibro_off") )
    navigator.vibrate([0])
  }
</script>
```

Мой код не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let doVibro = false;

document.getElementById("vibro_on").addEventListener('click', () => {
  doVibro = true;
});

document.getElementById("vibro_off").addEventListener('click', () => {
  doVibro = false;
});

document.getElementById("do-vibro").addEventListener('click', () => {
  doVibro ? navigator.vibrate([50]) : navigator.vibrate([0]);
});
```

```html
<button id="vibro_on">ON</button>
<button id="vibro_off">OFF</button>

<button onclick="vibro()" id="do-vibro">TEST</button>
```

Comment: При нажатии на ON срабатывает вибрация а мне нужно что бы срабатывала при нажатии на TEST, а кнопка ON и OFF включала или отключала вибрацию для кнопки TEST

Comment: @NikoPapchenko ок тогда так (см. ответ)

Comment: не срабатывает почему то. Вибрации вообще нету

Comment: Возможно вы не внимательн скопировали код. В т.ч. html

Comment: помещаю js код в <script></script> в html код и не срабатывает ничего так же помещаю в main.js так же не срабатывает.
Ваш код работает с сайта этого по линку.. не пойму что делаю не так

Comment: html тоже слегка изменён.... в частности `<button onclick="vibro()" id="do-vibro">TEST</button>`

Comment: Подскажите пжаоуйста еще. как сделать что бы устройство запоминало что я выбрал к примеру On и при перезагрузки страницы вибрация оставалась включена, а не слетала?

Comment: сохранять состояние в localStorage  и брать из него данные при перезагрузке

Comment: А если не затруднит можно пример кода, как из localStorage взять данные для моего кода?

Comment: Если есть ещё один вопрос - задайте его нажав кнопку "Задать вопрос". Текущий  ответ для текущего вопроса.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!